# Facebook Like Button: Titles and descriptions no longer display on FB

Tags: caching, metadata, facebook-like

We've had Facebook set up for a while, and its been working well...but recently I noticed that it's no longer including the article title and description when it shows up in my feed. I cleared my cache and the problem resolved itself, but we can't ask our users to clear their cache.

Is there a way to get Facebook to do this automatically, or some code that I can use to make it do so?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your url in the facebook Lint tool?
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I had a similar problem to this yesterday. The debugger got the correct data from my "og:" meta tags, but when actually clicking like button, none of that data was posted. Similarly, if I posted the "liked" url onto my wall, the preview got all the data, but when clicking 'share' nothing showed up.

As of this morning, all was looking better, but I didn't make a change. Facebook is known to break their own api at times and something that was working will stop suddenly, but then sometime later will work fine, all without us doing any updates. *shrug*

Run the url through the linter first, make sure it can grab your page's data.

- keith

Comment: Still trying to figure this one out - it seems that the problem has been happening over the last 3 weeks or so, so I went in and slightly changed the URLs, then republished. The problem corrected, but we lost all the existing Facebook like button counts for those pages. And I still don't know why it worked.

Comment: There's something of an explanation in here that helps illuminate what was going on: http://fbmhell.com/2010/10/breaking-facebook-share-cache/